# Вылетает с приложения метод startActivityResult()

Tags: java, android

Смотрю видео-уроки StartAndroid ,застрял на 29 (Вызываем активити и получаем результат) . Приложение вылетает ,не запускается  появляется окно с надписью "Unfortunately, OnClick has stoped".

Код обоих классов:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InputActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }

        String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        tv.setText("Your name is " + name);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input_activity);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Манифест :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".InputActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пытаться найти `view` так как делаете вы - грубая ошибка. В вашем случае методы `findViewById` вызовутся в момент создания класса. На этом этапе метод `onCreate`, и следовательно метод `setContentView` еще не вызывались, поэтому ваши поля будут всегда иметь значение `null`. Метод `findViewById` имеет смысл вызывать только после метода `setContentView`. Тогда разметка уже будет установлена, и если в ней будут существовать элементы с переданным ид, то метод поиска вернет их.

Далее, у вас в манифесте обе активити объявлены с фильтром

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

`android.intent.action.MAIN` указывает на то, что данная активити является точкой входа в приложение. В приложении может быть только одна точка входа.

`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` указывает на то,что значок этой активити следует поместить в средство запуска приложений системы.

Данные параметры должны быть назначены только **одной** активити, а не как у вас двум.

Comment: Спасибо , учту ваши замечания.

Answer (score 3):

Переместите инициализацию View в метод `onCreate();`

Вот так:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input_activity);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}
```